# Regular Expression in xml parsing

Tags: regex, perl

This is the content.

```
 <ext-link ext-link-type="uri" xlink:href="http://<xref&#x00A0;rid="x0026;AN=15230473">http://web.ebscohost.coms/ehost/detail&#x0026;#x003F;sid=d1f06770-cd74-4496-ae7b-7689ed05c6c4%40sessionmgr10&#x0026;#x0026;vid=1&#x0026;#x0026;hid=23&#x0026;#x0026;bdata=JnNpdGU9ZWhvc3QtbGl2ZQ%3d%3d&#x0026;#x0023;db=ufh&#x0026;#x0026;AN=15230473</xref>" link-type="url">
```

I want capture inside xlink:href="`http://<xref&#x00A0;rid="x0026;AN=15230473">http://web.ebscohost.coms/ehost/detail&#x0026;#x003F;sid=d1f06770-cd74-4496-ae7b-7689ed05c6c4%40sessionmgr10&#x0026;#x0026;vid=1&#x0026;#x0026;hid=23&#x0026;#x0026;bdata=JnNpdGU9ZWhvc3QtbGl2ZQ%3d%3d&#x0026;#x0023;db=ufh&#x0026;#x0026;AN=15230473</xref>`"

with double quotes.

I try this but cant get the which i need.

```
<ext-link(?: [^>]+)? xlink:href="([^"]+)"[^><]*>
```

Comment: some other attribute also come after the xline:href

Comment: not found the solution.

Comment: @avinash i need upto the double quote from xlink:href="(upto end)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\S+` to match one or more non-space characters.

```
<ext-link[^>]+? xlink:href="(\S+)"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/8)

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/^.*xlink:href=\"//; s/\">$//' file
```

Example:

```
sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD/SO$ cat file
<ext-link ext-link-type="uri" xlink:href="http://<xref&#x00A0;rid="x0026;AN=15230473">http://web.ebscohost.coms/ehost/detail&#x0026;#x003F;sid=d1f06770-cd74-4496-ae7b-7689ed05c6c4%40sessionmgr10&#x0026;#x0026;vid=1&#x0026;#x0026;hid=23&#x0026;#x0026;bdata=JnNpdGU9ZWhvc3QtbGl2ZQ%3d%3d&#x0026;#x0023;db=ufh&#x0026;#x0026;AN=15230473</xref>">


sdlcb@Goofy-Gen:~/AMD/SO$ perl -pe 's/^.*xlink:href=\"//; s/\">$//' file
http://<xref&#x00A0;rid="x0026;AN=15230473">http://web.ebscohost.coms/ehost/detail&#x0026;#x003F;sid=d1f06770-cd74-4496-ae7b-7689ed05c6c4%40sessionmgr10&#x0026;#x0026;vid=1&#x0026;#x0026;hid=23&#x0026;#x0026;bdata=JnNpdGU9ZWhvc3QtbGl2ZQ%3d%3d&#x0026;#x0023;db=ufh&#x0026;#x0026;AN=15230473</xref>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xlink:href=("(?:(?!<\/xref>).)*<\/xref>")
```

Try this.grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zU7dA5/6